# How to display custom form in django-allauth's social account sign up flow

Tags: python, django, facebook, django-allauth

I am trying to achieve all these together:

**A.** New users can sign up with or without using facebook.

**B.** They will all be presented with a form to fill out additional user information as part of the sign up flow.

**C.** New accounts will by default be inactive. Admins will need the additional user information when they manually activate (or delete) accounts.

---

I achieved **A** using *django-allauth* social accounts.

I achieved **C** by adding a listener to `django.db.models.signals.pre_save` and setting `user.active = False`

I partly achieved **B** by defining a custom `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS` in settings.py. However this only works for local "non-social" accounts as far as I can tell, since social logins seem to skip this form.

**My problem is that** when someone signs up with an allauth social account they don't have the chance to provide additional information since their account will be created without first displaying my custom sign up form.

Furthermore since all new accounts are automatically saved as inactive and that additional information is needed in order for admins to activate them I can't simply add that form to a "first time login flow" (note: it's not possible to log in to inactive accounts).

One way to solve this I guess would be to not automatically save accounts as inactive but instead work with permissions but I'd rather not rewrite all my views etc. if I can avoid it.

Any input would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this option to your `settings.py` file:

`SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP = False`